# Max and Min of 3 values using args[] in Java with Windows cmd

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

While compiling I got this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
class Maxmin {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (args.length >0) {


    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int tmp;
if (a>b) {
    tmp=a ;a=b ;b=tmp;

    }
if (b>c) {
    tmp=b ;b=c ;c=tmp;
}
if (a>c) {
    tmp=a ;a=c;c=tmp;
}
        System.out.println (a);

}
 }
 }
```

Comment: While compilation or while running the program? And what was the command for running the program?

Comment: the command is javac -d Maxmin.java

Comment: This is a runtime error. You need to run the program with 3 command line arguments for it to work.

Comment: That's what i am trying to do. Did you see any error in my code above?